# GRANDPA not finalizing with 2 of 3 nodes on network

Tags: grandpa, finality

I setup a small `3 node` network that is using BABE and GRANDPA. When all 3 nodes are connected, it can produce blocks and `finalize` them. When 2 of the 3 nodes are connected, it can produce `blocks` but NOT finalize them.

How can I configure GRANDPA so that blocks can be `finalized` when 2 of the `3 nodes` are connected?

Answer (score 10):

You can't do that in any safe manner. Every BFT consensus algorithm requires the total number of nodes to be at least `3f + 1` where `f` is the number of faulty nodes. In your case you have one faulty node, which means that the whole system should have at least 4 nodes, where 1 is faulty and the other 3 are healthy. With 3 nodes, no faulty node is tolerated.

In case you're interested in this here's the seminal paper on this topic: [The Byzantine Generals Problem - Leslie Lamport, Robert Shostak, and Marshall Pease](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/byz.pdf)

Comment: If you ever wondered why he called it the Byzantine generals problem, he tells us here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXt3-iZpQQc&t=9060s

Comment: Ok, got it. I do want 3 available validators because we are testing this, but we can create 4, or I guess 2 GRANDPA authorities and 3 BABE authorities. Will try this, thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question you should consider accepting the response :)